# Login button not working in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, login

In the CHECKOUT page, there are 2 options

1. checkout as guest    2. Register

[image]

When a new user registers

[image]

[image]

After clicking the continue button the page is redirected to the page shown below

[image]

and from here when we click "proceed to checkout" the page again is redirected to the checkout page (shown in the 1st screenshot) from where the user can login.

But after adding required data in the email and password fields when login button is pressed it tells its invalid.

[image]

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue related to LOGIN !!

Comment: check in after cusotmer registratoin customer add or not??

Comment: I have checked it , its not getting added now  !   Please tell me the solution if anyone knows it .

Answer (score 2):

its problem of form key

so please first add form key on that registration form

```
<div><input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" /></div>
```

Comment: I have made the above said changes in my code . its given below  :     <div><input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
<form id="co-billing-form" action=""> ...<fieldset></div>  But the data's registered are not getting added to the db as well as not able to LOGIN with the newly added data. Please tell me the changes i need to make !

Comment: add this code inside form not above form

Comment: I gave it as :                                                                                     `<form id="co-billing-form" name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" action="">
<fieldset> ...</fieldset> `                                                              But no change. When i register as a "**GUEST**" (shown in 1st screenshot) iam able to login after the registeration ; Both of the registration leads to a same page (shown in screenshot 2 and 3) but When i REGISTER iam not able to login. Anyother Solution !